# Sencha Touch 2.3..1 DataView is not loading Store details loaded later

Tags: dataview

I want to show some details on to Sencha Touch 2.3.1 DataView.
Actual Data to be loaded will come later to the DataView object creation.
I am not using Store proxy, but I have my own existing HTTP Request API for getting the JSON data. So once I get the data, I am creating a DataModel and adding to Store.
When I debug the code, I see it is adding and Store is populated with Data.

Now I am getting the DataView object with Ext.getCmp("") and setting the Store.
When I see the DataView object, I see the store (_store) containing the data (_data) in it.
But still the DataView is not populated with the datails.

Please help me in this context

**My DataModel:**

```
Ext.define('AlbumsListDM', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            "user",
            "title",
            "subtitle",
            "image"
        ]
    }
});
```

**My Store:**

```
Ext.define('AlbumsListStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        model: 'AlbumsListDM',
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
```

**My DataView:**

```
Ext.define(APP_NAME+'.view.AlbumsList', {
    extend: 'Ext.DataView',
    id: 'viewAlbumsListID',
    requires: ['AlbumsListDM'],
    config: {
        width:'100%',
        height:'100%',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'dataview',
            scrollable: true,
            inline: true,
            cls: 'dataview-inline',
            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<div class="img" style="background-image: url({image});">{title}</div>')
        }]
    }
});
```

**My Construction of store and updating DataView:**

```
Ext.create('AlbumsListStore', { id: 'AlbumsListStoreID' });

var albumsList = myJsonData;
var albumsListStore = Ext.getStore('AlbumsListStoreID');
var count = albumsList.length;
for(var index = 0; index < count; index++) {
    albumsListStore.add(Ext.create('AlbumsListDM', albumsList[index]));
}
var viewAlbumsList = Ext.getCmp("viewAlbumsListID");
viewAlbumsList.setStore(albumsListStore);
```

Thanks
Siva